# How to open tensorflow xla

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorflow-xla

I tried the example under tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist & try to apply xla for speedup.
However, I cannot see XlaLaunch as https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit said.

Also, I try to profile execution time by:

```
  train_loops = 100000
  t_start = time.time()
  for i in range(train_loops):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

    # Create a timeline for the last loop and export to json to view with
    # chrome://tracing/.
    if i == train_loops - 1:
      sess.run(train_step,
               feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                          y_: batch_ys},
               options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
               run_metadata=run_metadata)
      trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
      with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as trace_file:
        trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
    else:
      sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  tdiff = time.time() - t_start
  print("tdiff", tdiff, " i = ", i)
```

[image]

**It seems to be no difference between with & without xla.**

**I saw some articles said I should "rebuild" tensorflow source to open xla? should I?**

**Is there any other way to open it? Or it has been opened by default but I am in wrong way to use it.**

**Is there benchmark to profile the speedup once xla has been opened?**

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

The latest TensorFlow binaries available in pip may include XLA support built in already. `pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu --upgrade --force-reinstall` will provide this support for you (as of TF 1.12). This works for me on Ubuntu with or without NVIDIA GPU support, but not on my MacBook. If your binary doesn't, you'll know below when trying to use the benchmark.

If you are properly calling the XLA JIT and you do not have support built into the binary, you would get an exception. Something like

`ValueError: Op type not registered 'XlaClusterOutput' in binary running on localhost. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) tf.contrib.resampler should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed. while building NodeDef 'tower_0/v/output0'`

If you get this, try installing the latest tensorflow, or even tf-nightly. If that doesn't work, time to cross your fingers and [build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

Where in your code did you enable XLA?

For a test benchmark, you can try to the official TensorFlow Benchmarks repository [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks). You can use synthetic data if you don't have ImageNet downloaded. You can enable or disable XLA with the flag `--xla_compile=True` or `False`.

For instance:

```
python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --num_batches=2000 --xla_compile=True
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to enable XLA without installing Tensorflow from source with whatever flags is to follow the instructions in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44683 and set environment variables when you run your script that run the training:

```
>>> TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices python my_training_script.py
```

You should then see the log message:

```
XLA service 0x95522ao initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
  StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```