# Anyone knows how to disable xla compiler on cloud TPUv3 node instance?

Tags: tpu, xla

I'm trying to profile a tensorflow based network, but XLA fusion makes it difficult to isolate the function I want to know about.

Anyone knows how to disable XLA compiler? I tried --xla_compile=False as below

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890108/how-to-open-tensorflow-xla#:~:text=You%20can%20enable%20or%20disable,%2D%2Dxla_compile%3DTrue%20or%20False%20.&text=Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,-One%20way%20to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890108/how-to-open-tensorflow-xla#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enable%20or%20disable,%2D%2Dxla_compile%3DTrue%20or%20False%20.&text=Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,-One%20way%20to)